# Python logging API printing filename as `<string>`

Tags: python, logging, format

I have a python script that is executed by my application. The script uses the built-in `logging` API from python. The problem I'm having is that the file name in all log messages is written as `<string>`. When I run the same code in a snippet, it runs fine.
Below is the code I use to configure the logger:

```
import logging
import os
import sys
from logging import FileHandler, StreamHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('update_menu')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create handlers and set level to debug
fileHandler = FileHandler(filename='/home/fguimaraes/work/update_menu.log')
fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

consoleHandler = StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s;File:%(filename)s;Function:%(funcName)s;Line:%(lineno)d')

# add formatter to log
fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add log to logger
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

Comment: Can you show the logger call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your script is being read into memory and executed as a string using e.g. `exec`, which means that there is no filename for the script. Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(filename)s: %(message)s')
logging.debug('This is a test')
vinay@theta-trusty-unity:~/projects/orbitilweb$ python /tmp/test.py
test.py: This is a test
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open('/tmp/test.py') as f: data = f.read()
... 
>>> exec data
<string>: This is a test
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

for those looking for a solution, I had the same issue and I decided to solve it by using the below instead of exec:

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'myscript.py'])
```